# Determine android device lock status?

Tags: android

Is there a way to get the device lock status (enabled/disabled) of an android device? I have been looking at the android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager, but doesn't seems like anything available in that class.

Note: I already knew how to lock the device progrmatically, my question above is get the device lock status, whether its enabled/not.

Comment: what do you mean by "lock status" ?